# Only remember part and format of BitLocker password

Tags: keys

I am a complete novice to the field, however I made the mistake of locking my Macbook bootcamp partition with a bitlocker password which I cannot remember entirely.

There isn't much irreplaceable data on the partition, but I would like to know whether there's any way to recover the password.

the format was :

Dictionaryword&dictionaryword301

What I have forgotten are the two words, which were standard English words (albeit long ones). The first one was capitalised.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions,

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be a better fit for security or perhaps superuser or software recommendations stackexchanges

Comment: hashcat or John the ripper should do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't really on topic for our site, so it will probably be closed.

But you might want to look at something like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).

Either that or just grab a dictionary of English words and write a program to put combinations of them together and submit them as password guesses.